# Why would an OpenGL polygon ignore two vertices?

Tags: c++, opengl

I am attempting to draw a star (this is my first OpenGL attempt), but the bottom and left sides are drawing as flat, even though I have vertices set up for them.  What am I missing here?

```
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glVertex2i(30,0);
    glVertex2i(105,55);
    glVertex2i(180,0);
    glVertex2i(150,75);
    glVertex2i(210, 90);
    glVertex2i(135, 135);
    glVertex2i(105, 210);
    glVertex2i(75, 135);
    glVertex2i(0, 90);
    glVertex2i(55, 75);
glEnd();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Polygons defined with `GL_POLYGON` **must** be convex. You can't make a star with it, because it has convex and concave parts.

The proper way to draw your star would be to define all the triangles that make up a star and draw them in a list of `GL_TRIANGLES`. `GL_POLYGON` is deprecated from modern opengl anyway, so you would be wise not to pay much attention to it.

Comment: That would make sense, thank you!  (I can't accept yet, but I will when I can)